# Exclude Single Bean using @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-autoconfiguration

I want to exclude a single Spring bean that's included in the packages scanned by Spring's component scan.  I'd like to do this by using some kind of exclude parameter of the @SpringBootApplication annotation.  All of Spring Boot's documentation seems to explain how to exclude "auto configuration classes" like LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class.  I don't want to exclude an auto configuration class - I'd just like to exclude a single bean. I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.4. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is this your own bean? I mean, can you change it? Or is it from a library?

Comment: no - it's from a library

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.